# Pagination not working only with a certain query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, pagination, kaminari

I am using Kaminari gem to paginate using ajax

i have three paginations on the same page

```
    @all_questions = Question.where.not(id: current_user.question_ids).page(params[:unanswered]).per(1)

    @wrong = Tracker.where("user_id = ? AND correct = ?", current_user, false).page(params[:wrong_answers]).per(1)

    @answered = Tracker.where("user_id = ? AND answered = ?", current_user, true).page(params[:all_answered]).per(1)
```

while the last two of the above instance variables correctly work. The first one when i click the next button, while i see the ajax request happening in the rails console, it does not refresh the page.

in my view

```
<%= paginate @all_questions, :remote => true, :param_name => "unanswered" %>
<%= paginate @wrong, :remote => true, :param_name => "wrong_answers" %>
<%= paginate @answered, :remote => true, :param_name => "all_answered" %>
```

Anyone knows why?

html

```
     <section role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true" class="content" id="panel2-2">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="large-10 large-offset-1 columns">
            <div class="panel questions-progress-panel">
              <ul>
                <div id="unanswered">
                  <%= render partial: "all_questions" %>
                </div>
                <div id="paginator4" class="text-center paginator">
                  <%= paginate @all_questions, :remote => true, :param_name => "unanswered" %>
                </div>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
```

@all_questions partial

```
<% @all_questions.each do |q| %>
  <li>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="large-8 medium-8 small-8 columns">
          <p class="question-title"> <%= q.description %> </p>
        </div>
        <div class="large-4 medium-4 small-4 columns text-right">
          <%= link_to "Go", category_question_path(q.category,q), class:"button round success" %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What is `@all_questions` like? Does it contain questions at least?

Comment: yes it contains two after executing the query. I can see them showing, shows two pages as well [1,2 next last] in pagination controls, its just not the pagination working. Does Kaminari expect a certain structure or something?

Comment: If I remember correctly Kaminari expects a `Relations` type of the structure. Could you inspect in console what type of the class is using all of those results above e.g. put `p @all_questions` , `p @wrong` etc. in your code and run it, and then take a look at a console, what it displays. What type of those relations are

Comment: Hm, but if it displays the results correctly at least on one of the pages, then it should be working. Check the web-browser's console for javascript errors instead of Rails errors, maybe that will give you a hint. Also, is the `unanswered` parameter being set when paginating those results for all questions?

Comment: @Aleks i have used `p` on the first two instance variables both display `#<ActiveRecord::Relation` . Also when pressing the button to show the next record (talking for @all_questions) it does fetch it, i can see it in the console. its just not displayed, no errors in console, maybe something wrong with my html?

Comment: @PetrosKyriakou how does you corresponding `js.erb` looks like ?

Comment: @dkp thank you! i totally forgot that i have to add some lines in my .js.erb to change the view! that was it! cheers!

Comment: @dkp sorry for taking you the answer on previous question. Maybe you can create a new answer on this to get accepted on this one, if Petros accepts it, or course, as you have pointed to the solution

Comment: @Aleks You answer was indeed simply efficient one!! :) Hope Petros get through this problem!

Comment: cheers to both of you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your corresponding `js.erb` could look like this:

```
$('#unanswered').html('<%= escape_javascript render(all_questions) %>');
$("#paginator4").html('<%= escape_javascript(paginate(@all_questions, :remote => true).to_s) %>');
```